# Is there a theorem relating trivial homomorphism to the center of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading through this post:
[Show that Sylow-P Subgroup Lies in the Center of G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596555/show-that-a-sylow-p-group-lies-in-the-center-of-g)

The explanation says that because every element of $H$ induces the trivial homomorphism to $Aut(H),$ this means that $H$ is in the center of $G.$ This is not a fact that I have heard before and I am not following why this implies that $H$ is in the center of $G$. Could someone explain this in more detail for me?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not what the answer says. You should read it again more carefully.

Comment: @Ted "Thus every element induces the trivial automorphism, meaning H is in the center."

Comment: @Ted Regardless, I do not understand what is happening here and your response to have me read the one sentence explanation that I did not understand and wanted clarification on again, is 100% unhelpful. Just trying to learn here.

Comment: Did you notice in that post that the subgroup $H$ is 1) a normal subgroup of the group $G$, 2) has a prime order $p$, and 3) $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of order $G$?

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes, but I am struggling to connect all the dots here.

Comment: Very well. Then you probably understand how the homomorphism $f:\,G\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is obtained?

Comment: Yes, I follow up until the very last sentence of his explanation.

Comment: Great. Then $f(G)<\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ and by the Lagrange theorem $|f(G)|$ divides both the order of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ and the order of the group $G$. Isn't that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133247/discussion-between-mike-and-kabenyuk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element of $G$ (not $H$, as you wrote in your post) induces the trivial automorphism on $Aut(H)$. Inducing the trivial automorphism means that $ghg^{-1} = h$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, i.e., $gh=hg$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. This means $H$ is in the center of $G$.